# Problem with FB dialog when no user logged in

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I've searched around for hours, finding many related posts but without being able to solve my problem.

The goal is to show a simple "Post to your wall" dialog using the FB JS SDK. Using the code [here](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui) works like a charm in default cases.

However, because I'm calling my dialog showing function from inside a game engine (that is, no user click event), the dialog from the above wiki is blocked by popup blockers. Therefore, I tested using display:'iframe' instead, and it works. The problem, though, is when there is no user logged in. In 'popup' mode, the user is presented with an login dialog instead before showing the actual 'Post to your wall' dialog. But in 'iframe' mode this dialog never appears, instead there is a loading screen which goes on forever.

**Summary**:

Popup mode: works even though the user is not logged in, but is blocked by popup blockers

Iframe mode: Fails if no user is logged in, but isn't blocked by popup blockers

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are limitations on which dialogs can be used in which display modes. You can't authorise a user in an iframe because of security risks, you have to have a pop up, or a redirect to authorise.

"iframe: Display the dialog in a lightbox iframe on the current page. Because of the risk of clickjacking, this is only allowed for some certain dialogs, and requires you to pass a valid access_token." - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

Edit to add: You might also want to read the policies and guideline documentation. Facebook recommend that you only show these dialogs in response to a direct click/action that the user has taken, to prevent your app looking spammy. Automatically posting stuff to users' profiles is an easy way to lose trust. Maybe you could rethink your solution so that your prompt shows up in response to the user clicking on something?

Comment: tnx for your hints Abby. In fact, the user is clicking something, but inside a 3d game engine (Unity3d). That click triggers a javascript function on the page that holds the game. that's why the popup blockers doesn't recognize the click, and acts like it was in page load or something (and blocks it).

Comment: in that case, maybe you want to make a server side graph api request rather than showing a dialog? You can create your own pop-up/window in game to provide space to the user to add their message and tell them you are going to post something, then publish from the server using the graph: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing. This way you won't have to deal with extra javascript, browser compat, pop up blockers etc.

Comment: I suppose that is doable, however it would be much more convenient to use the existing FB dialogs, as people recognize them and know how to handle them. I'm thinking of doing a workaround, where I hide/show a html button on top of the game interface, which the user can press to post to his wall. In that case I can use 'popup' display mode, which is working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to place this code?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
I have added it to my page (in tabs), and it works good.

Comment: tried that the very first, but that code is blocked by popup blockers too (see comment above).